# How to save the command line output to a file IN REALTIME

Tags: command-line, bash, suspend, logging

I have made a bash script that is designed to backup my PC every night around 4 o'clock. After the backup has finished, my system goes back into sleep.

Currently I am using `| tee -a $LOGFILE` to log all the commands, however, the logging is not in real-time. When my computer goes into sleep, it hasn't written the file yet, so I need to wake up my PC before I can see the changes on the webdav backup location.

This is very annoying since I can't look quickly up why it hasn't backed up last night.

Comment: Show this script

Comment: Probably a combination of http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ and of not issuing a `sync` before going back to sleep... but yes, having the script will be better.

Comment: @Rmano I don't feel like showing the script because of some security issues. I'll try the sync option as mentioned in the answer from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the available information this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but... if the script is the one that issues the command to go back to sleep (which one?) [the problem may be stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/). So I will

1. prepare a script that does the backup but will not go to sleep, call it `bck_script`.
2. prepare another script that sends the PC to sleep, call it `sleep_script`

Schedule a third script with

```
bck_script | tee $LOGFILE
sync
sleep 30
sleep_script
```

... where the sleep is probably overdoing it but well --- I really do not trust a lot `sync` over network or with "intelligent" (read strangely buffered) SSDs.

Comment: Luckely I don't have a ssd in that system. Thanks! The test result will come out tonight, so I'll update asap.

Comment: I found out that the log was being updated locally, but doesn't get mirrored instantly to the WebDAV drive. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: EDIT: After the backup completed, the logfile is synced!

Comment: @tim687 --- happy it helped. Now you now what you should do... http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ☺

Comment: Yeah sure, I always do that :-P. Just wanted to make sure that it really was the answer. What the problem is here, is that the local logfile is realtime, but the logfile doesn't get updated on the webdav drive.